# Error en consulta (Select)

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo problemas en mi consulta, la función de mi modulo básicamente es enviar una copia automática de correo de los datos que ingreso el usuario en el formulario, cuando el usuario cierra el ticket (modificación del ticket).

Mi consulta lo que hace es verificar el correo de la ultima linea con `ORDER BY  t.id DESC LIMIT 1`   (el campo  id en mi BD es autoincrementable)según el campo user_id que se inserta en mi tabla tickets y con un **inner join** lo busca en la tabla foránea usuario con el campo id y al obtenerlo es al que le envía el correo automático.

**Ejemplo**

Si el ticket es el numero 10 y otros usuarios ya ingresaron varios tickets ejemplo el 15, entonces mi consulta al hacer el `ORDER BY  t.id DESC LIMIT 1` me trae el correo del usuario con el  ticket 15 (que en este caso seria el ultimo en mi BD)pero tendria que ser en este caso traerme los datos y el correo del usuario que levanto el ticket  10, entonces como siempre toma el ultimo registro le manda siempre el correo al usuario que este en mi ultima linea y esto es erróneo.

En **$query** lo que realiza es un inner join para obtener los campos de otras tablas foraneas.

En **$envio** lo que hace es consulta el email del usuario con el campo user_id de la tabla user y lo compara con la tabla ticket  con el campo $id

**Consultas:**

```html
   

 $query= "SELECT
      t.id, t.title, t.process_1, t.process_2, t.updated_at, t.created_at, 
  ki.name kind_desc,
  us.name user_desc,
  cat.name cat_desc,
  pri.name pri_desc,
  tur.name tur_desc,
  are.name are_desc,
  sta.name sta_desc,
  fin.name fin_desc,
  ing.name ing_desc,
  sub.name sub_desc,
  t.comments

 
   FROM
    ticket t
    LEFT JOIN kind ki ON ki.id = t.kind_id
    LEFT JOIN user  us ON us.id = t.user_id
    LEFT JOIN category cat ON cat.id = t.category_id
    LEFT JOIN priority pri ON pri.id = t.priority_id
    LEFT JOIN turno tur ON tur.id = t.turno_id
    LEFT JOIN area are ON are.id = t.area_id
    LEFT JOIN estatus sta ON sta.id = t.estatus_id
    LEFT JOIN final fin ON fin.id = t.final_id
    LEFT JOIN ingeniero ing ON ing.id = t.ing_id
    LEFT JOIN sub_categoria sub ON sub.id = t.subcategoria_id
    ORDER BY  t.id DESC LIMIT 1"; 




    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

    $datos = mysqli_fetch_object($result);



    $envio = "SELECT u.email as email FROM ticket t INNER JOIN user u ON u.id = t.user_id WHERE u.id = t.user_id  order by t.id DESC LIMIT 1 ";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($con,$envio);




        $cabeceras = 'From: ' . "Soporte Técnico " . "\r\n";
        if($row = $resultado->fetch_array())
           $cabeceras .= 'Bcc: '.$row['email']."\r\n";
        $cabeceras .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8";
```

Comment: Creo que te estás confundiendo con el funcionamiento del `LIMIT 1`. Se aplica al resultado de la consulta completa y no únicamente a la primera tabla, por lo que si un mismo `t.id` tiene varios registros en otras tablas, se quedará únicamente con uno de los registros. Si lo que quieres es obtener los datos del ticket que cerró el usuario, haz una búsqueda por el identificador de ese ticket, y no una búsqueda completa de todos ellos.

Comment: @OscarGarcia lo que tengo entendido que `LIMIT 1` te trae en este caso 1 fila y si le aplicas `DESC` traerá solo el valor valor de la ultima fila, de echo ya realice la búsqueda así como indicas pero en mi array me trae todos los valores de mi tabla, no se como realizar esa consulta.

Comment: Probablemente lo que deseas encontrar no es la última fila, si no la fila correspondiente al ticket que estás cerrando. En todo momento estás trabajando con la totalidad del contenido de la tabla, no con el ticket en cuestión. Un simple `WHERE t.id = ?` te ayudaría a obtener únicamente el ticket que estás cerrando, suponiendo que tienes almacenado en algún lado el `id` que muestras en el formulario que el usuario usa para cerrar el ticket de alguna forma (según tu redacción, parece que es en la variable `$id`).

Comment: @OscarGarcia exacto eso es lo que necesito, segun yo asi es mi  `WHERE t.id = t.user_id`  que buscara el no de ticket (id) con el no. de usuario (user_id), pero hago la consulta y no me arroja ningún resultado

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95211/discussion-between-carlos-and-oscargarcia).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás haciendo búsquedas genéricas en la tabla sin limitar los resultados al identificador del ticket que estás cerrando, `t.id`, que tienes almacenado en la variable `$id` de PHP.

Para hacerlo debes sustituir el `LIMIT 1` por un `WHERE t.id = ?` y asignar a ese marcador el contenido de `$id` usando consultas preparadas de la siguiente manera:

```
$query= "
   SELECT
     t.id, t.title, t.process_1, t.process_2,
     t.updated_at, t.created_at, ki.name kind_desc,
     us.name user_desc, us.email email, cat.name cat_desc,
     pri.name pri_desc,
     tur.name tur_desc,
     are.name are_desc,
     sta.name sta_desc,
     fin.name fin_desc,
     ing.name ing_desc,
     sub.name sub_desc,
     t.comments
   FROM ticket t
   LEFT JOIN kind ki ON ki.id = t.kind_id
   LEFT JOIN user  us ON us.id = t.user_id
   LEFT JOIN category cat ON cat.id = t.category_id
   LEFT JOIN priority pri ON pri.id = t.priority_id
   LEFT JOIN turno tur ON tur.id = t.turno_id
   LEFT JOIN area are ON are.id = t.area_id
   LEFT JOIN estatus sta ON sta.id = t.estatus_id
   LEFT JOIN final fin ON fin.id = t.final_id
   LEFT JOIN ingeniero ing ON ing.id = t.ing_id
   LEFT JOIN sub_categoria sub ON sub.id = t.subcategoria_id
   WHERE t.id = ?
";
/* Preparamos la consulta SQL */
$consulta = mysqli_prepare($con, $query);
/* Le asignamos al marcador "?" el valor de $id como entero (i) */
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($consulta, 'i', $id);
/* Realizamos la consulta */
mysqli_stmt_execute($consulta);
/* Obtenemos el resultado */
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($consulta);
/* Trabajamos con el resultado igual que lo haríamos habitualmente */
$datos = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
/* No necesitas la segunda consulta para obtener el email */
$cabeceras = "From: Soporte Técnico\r\n";
if (!empty($datos->email)) {
  $cabeceras .= 'Bcc: ' . $datos->email . "\r\n";
}
$cabeceras .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
```